# Object/Class family

Tags: class, object, pascal

I've got a problem with Class data structures in Object Pascal.
I want to make a family of Classes/Objects that can only be accesses via the main class.
Also these subclasses should be able to access the fields of each class that they are created by.
This is what i got:

```
ClassOne = class;
ClassTwo = class;
ClassThree = class;

ClassOne = class(TObject)
    private
        FieldOne: ClassTwo;
        FieldTwo: Byte;

    public
        procedure MethodOne(Something: Byte);
end;

ClassTwo = class(TObject)
    private
        FieldOne: ClassThree;

    public
        procedure MethodOne();
end;

ClassThree = class(TObject)
    public
        procedure MethodOne();
end;
```

This isn't working the way i want it to, it should be like this:
ClassOne is the master class that got everything together.
All other classes: ClassTwo and ClassThree can only be used (inside) by ClassOne.
ClassTwo and ClassThree should also be able to read fields of the master ClassOne as well as other classes that created it.

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClassTwo = class(ClassOne)
...
End;

ClassThree = class(ClassOne)
...
END;
```

ClassOne can be declared the way you did.

UPDATE

you have to make ClassTwo field in class ClassOne protectrd instead of private. Protected means the field can directly accessed by all subclasses.

TObject is the common baseclass for all classes in object pascal. To achieve inheritence you have assign your prefetred base class and replace TObject with it. Now ClassTwo and ClassThree inherit all methods and properties of ClassOne

Comment: They can still be created outside of the ClassOne and also will give a problem when having same names of fields/methods.

Comment: Ok what you are looking for is for Nested Classes. I dont know if there is a concept for that in Object Pascal. the Problem with the fieldNames is logical because they are ambigious if there occure duplicate names for parent and subclass fields

Comment: This is Exacly what i needed. Only one problem left, how to access outter class ? Do i need to store the instance of the outter one and pass it to the inner class or there is some other way ?

Comment: Yeah right you need to set the instance from the outter one by passing it to the inner one after creation. I have to say that it is a cyclic dependency which always difficult to handle but this is not part of the question.